# Python Sorting./Splitting a Dictionary Value into more values based on a parameter

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary with the key of "Alpha" and the following values:

```
my_dictionary = {
    "Alpha" : "AB1,BC1,SA1,SK1/BC2,TC2/IT3"   
    }
```

How would I split up some of the values of the dictionary with the parameter of '/'?
So I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
my_dictionary = {
    "Alpha" : "AB1,BC1,SA1,SK1,BC2,TC2,IT3"   
    }
```

Comment: You're not really splitting anything, because it's still a string.  Just do `my_dictionary["Alpha"] = my_dictionary["Alpha"].replace('/', ',')` if you want to modify that specific value.

Comment: Or did you mean that the value for `"Alpha"` is `["AB1", "BC1", "SA1", "SK1/BC2", "TC2/IT3"]`?

Answer (score 1):

As the value of Alpha is a string, you can replace every slash with a comma.

```
my_dictionary.get("Alpha", "").replace('/', ',')
```

To update the value you can either reassign it or use `.update()` and `.get()`

```
my_dictionary["Alpha"] = my_dictionary["Alpha"].replace('/', ',')

my_dictionary.update(
    {"Alpha": my_dictionary.get("Alpha", "").replace('/', ',')})
```

If you want to split your string into a list of values, you can use `.split(',')` like this:

```
my_dictionary["Alpha"].split(",")
```